# webkitTransitionEnd not firing

Tags: javascript, css, webkit-transform

I'm not sure what exactly happened, but I am pretty sure this was working at one point.

The event just isn't firing (or I am not catching it properly)

```
var $zoomBox = $('#zoomBox');
$zoomBox.bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    alert("test");
});
$('.button').click(function (e) {
    $zoomBox.css('-webkit-transform', 'matrix(2,1,1,2,300, 100)');
});
```

see fiddle below. After the box finishes transitioning, an alert should pop up, but the alert is not displaying.

http://jsfiddle.net/cGwb4/1/

Comment: I checked it at http://jsfiddle.net/cGwb4/1/ it working fine.

Comment: No you are true no alert is there let me try.

Comment: As jfreind00 said, you have to give it some transition: http://jsfiddle.net/cGwb4/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no transition specified in the CSS, so you aren't getting a transition at all.  You're just changing the CSS for which there is no `webkitTransitionEnd` event.

See the fixed example here (in Chrome or Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/75Mh2/ where I've added:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s;
```

Comment: Or '-webkit-transform 0s' if you want the same visual effect as the original question.

Comment: @jezternz - Not sure why you'd set a transition to 0s though.